# NullPointerException when mapping from one Reactor Mono to another one

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have two Reactor Monos so when the first completes(SecurityUtils.getUsernameAuthenticated()) I have to execute the second Mono and then return the result of the second Mono.

I have done this:

```
@Override
    public Mono<Timestamp> findLastTimeConnected() {
        return SecurityUtils.getUsernameAuthenticated().map(connectionRepository::findLastTimeConnected);
    }
```

But I got this exception when findLastTimeConnected returns null:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: The mapper [com.structural.domain.user.service.UserConnectionServiceImpl$$Lambda$1884/0x00000008011b3440] returned a null value.
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:108) ~[reactor-core-3.4.19.jar:3.4.19]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74) ~[reactor-core-3.4.19.jar:3.4.19]
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Null is not a valid value in Reactor types. If you are fine with an empty `Mono` in such scenarios, then you can use `mapNotNull` instead of `map`: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#mapNotNull-java.util.function.Function-

Comment: Ok but with map or mapNotNull as I read the function executed is syncronous. How can this be done in an asyncronous mode? Maybe with doOnNext and thenReturn?

Comment: You didn't share connectionRepository, so I'm not sure what's going on there. For asynchronous execution, you should use flatMap and modify connectionRepository to return empty Mono instead of null.